# Ionic Failed - Android Build

Tags: android, ionic-framework

This is the output I get

```
ionic cordova build android  --stacktrace
> cordova build android
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        (truncated) ... ld UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
        :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1026Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareOrgXwalkXwalk_core_library22525614Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareArmv7DebugDependencies
        :compileArmv7DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
        :compileArmv7DebugRenderscript
        :generateArmv7DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :mergeArmv7DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :compileArmv7DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :generateArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :mergeArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :createXwalkCommandLineFileArmv7Debug
        :generateArmv7DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :generateArmv7DebugResources
        :mergeArmv7DebugResources
        :processArmv7DebugManifest
        :processArmv7DebugResources
        :generateArmv7DebugSources
        :incrementalArmv7DebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :compileArmv7DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
        :compileArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
        :prePackageMarkerForArmv7Debug
        :transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Debug UP-TO-DATE
        :mergeArmv7DebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
        :transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForArmv7Debug UP-TO-DATE
        :processArmv7DebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
        :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForArmv7Debug FAILED


        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 40.152 secs
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForArmv7Debug'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties
                File1: C:\Users\A2\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.8.0\5a11f020cce2d11eb71ba916700600e18c4547e7\okhttp-3.8.0.jar
                File2: C:\Users\A2\Desktop\posApAp\posApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\10.2.6\jars\classes.jar


        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForArmv7Debug'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties
                File1: C:\Users\A2\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.8.0\5a11f020cce2d11eb71ba916700600e18c4547e7\okhttp-3.8.0.jar
                File2: C:\Users\A2\Desktop\posApAp\posApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\10.2.6\jars\classes.jar


        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Can somebody please let me know how to sort this issue? Thank you. 
It says Duplicate class copied. How to solve this issue. I tried exclude in build.gradle but it's not helping.

Comment: update your android sdk then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the question. 
I needed to do exclude META-INF

Comment: How do you exclude META-INF in this case?  Update a config file?  Run another ionic command?  Delete some files?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue while building my app and I solved it by

1. Update android SDK
2. Remove platform using  proper command

   `ionic cordova platform remove android` (if you are using latest CLI)
3. then add android platform again and build it.

if it still dont work, try downgrading nodejs to previous version and build.